# How to keep Macbook Pro external monitor in use when opening the lid?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MacBook Pro with a broken screen. It is functional with the lid closed and an external monitor, keyboard, and mouse. However, if I open the lid (to use the camera) the external monitor goes blank and I cannot do anything because the screen is broken. Is there a way to configure things with the lid closed such that when the lid opens the external monitor is retained?

Comment: The title and body have different questions. Macs work fine with the lid closed. Use an external dcreen with a built-in camera. My Apple 27" display although older than my powerbook still works fine with the required adaptors, plus ext keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Also make sure mirroring is off and that the external monitor has the toolbar on it ie it is primary.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Initially the external monitor did not display at all when the lid the was up. Then the external monitor spontaneously started working in non-mirrored mode with the lid up but when I opened System Preferences it was on the broken screen not on the monitor. Then somehow System Preferences appeared on the monitor and I was able to configure it as mirrored.

Comment: An answer that essentially says that it fixed itself spontaneously is not very helpful.